# Plot on the next slide

Tags: r, plot, r-markdown, beamer

I am preparing some slides in RMarkdown, and I need to plot the code on one slide and the plot on the next one, so I frequently find myself doing something on the lines of

`````
```{r, eval=FALSE}
plot(x ,y)
````

---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(x, y)
```
`````

Is there a more elegant way to doing things that would avoid repetitions?

Comment: depends on your output format for slides, but a `\newpage` in Rmarkdown might create a new page, and maybe a new slide for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of that create an object and call it

`````
```{r}
plt <- plot(x ,y)
````

---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plt
```
`````

Answer (score 0):

In case you would like to split all your plots over two frames:

````
---
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \renewenvironment{Shaded}{\begin{onlyenv}<.(1)>\begin{snugshade}}{\end{snugshade}\end{onlyenv}\pause}
---


```{r,  include=TRUE}
plot(pressure)
```
````